# App is not running in the below 9 version in cordova

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I renamed an existing project in cordova. The new renamed app is running in the > 9 version, but I want my app to run in below 9 version too. However, the existing project which is not renamed is running in below 9 version also.  I am able to install my app on a device but while launching it is crashing. I tried to find the mistake but it fails. I don’t know why it is not launching. Could anyone please tell me what might be wrong?

Comment: Are there any log files that could point you in the right direction?

Comment: Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _objc_unsafeClaimAutoreleasedReturnValue
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/6566A7E3-1032-495D-8B83-8580658F59CE/TimeOut.app/TimeOut
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
  Dyld Version: 353.10
THIS IS I AM GETTING IN DEVICE LOGS

Answer (score 0):

Cordova removed iOS8 support in it's latest version (see this [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12523)) because it is their policy to only support the current iOS version (10) and one version before. But you can always manually change the deployment-target back to 8.0 in xcode. Open you xcode project select the CordovaLib project and change the deployment target to 8.0 ([Apple developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW47)). Of course you will also have to do the same for you main projects target.

Comment: I am changing the CordovaLib project deployment target to 8.0 even though  I am getting the same issue. And also I am using Urban Airship Plugin too.

Comment: Did you make sure you changed *all* deployment-targets in the CordovaLib, for the Project "CordovaLib" and for the Targets "CordovaLib" and "Cordova" and of course your main project? If thei Urban Airship plugin contains another xcode project wich has a deployment target you will have to change it to 8.0 too.

Comment: Yes. I changed everywhere.

Comment: Did you already try removing the whole `platforms` folder and readding it with `cordova platform add ios`?

Comment: Yes. I am doing. It is showing like UIWebview issue.